# while i cleanup my project my R.java file deleted automatically

Tags: android, r.java-file

How can i recover my R.java file in my project .
When i clean up my project in gen folder all the java files are deleted automatically .
if i make my project once again or not.

Comment: ya i got. but first of you delete the that project in which no R.java file and once again you import that project  "if u have back up " and then first of all you do right click on the project then you  -> select the  Android Tools options then -> select Add Support Library and install ...

Comment: when i click om Add  Support library it install, that time  you should be connect to internet. Automatically install

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning a project removes all auto-generated files including R.java.
Once you build your project(and if doesn't contains errors), you will automatically get your `R.java`.

Go to `project-->Build Project` to build your project

In my experience if `R.java` is not being automatically created then there is an error somewhere in your xml.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning a project removes all auto-generated files. Building the project it should automatically create them. When you Clean a project.

**if R.java is not being automatically created then there is an error somewhere in your xml. Triple check everything.**

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. If you are using Eclipse with the ADT plugin, you can set the project to build automatically. This means that everything (including the R source) will be rebuilt after every file save and after every clean command.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok, you're not suppose to touch on these files generated on the gen folder. Every time you perform a clean build these files will be recreated based on the Android XML files you have. So the R.java file will be regenerated again automatically, it will only fail if there's any problem on one of the resource files (drawables, layouts, etc), if so you should be able to see the errors on the Console view.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced same problem long back. The solution which i came across was that there was an error in my xml's(layout, values,string,drawables). 
due to this reason R.java was not building poperly and it was getting deleted everytime i build the project.

Comment: no some time they show the  error .means we check all the project but we didn't find the error .Then we cleanup the project all the gen folder files are deleted automatically,because some time project did not fin all the library in the project so  "add support  library" .

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, the R.Java seems to delete if you save too many files at
one go. if you highlight the file in package expolorer, then right
click propeties, select builders, unclick all the builders and OK.
Then go back in and re-click the items again.

Answer (score -1):

I too have experienced such a problem just now. I resolved it by going to the 
Console box, and there was error showing in the XML file.  I solved this error in the XML file, I saved and then cleaned the project.  `R.java` was re-created again in `res` folder.

Comment: In the future, please type as if you were using a keyboard and not like you're on a mobile phone. I had to edit it because it looked God awful.  Apologies if you're offended.